# libOpenCL.so incompatible for arm64-v8a ABI?

Tags: android, c++, opencl

I want to run a native android app which uses the Qualcomm OpenCL SDK. Therefore I have linked my target `native_lib.cpp` against the provided `libOpenCL.so`, included `opencl.hpp` in my native code and added the following lines to my CMakeLists.txt:

```
include_directories(opencl-sdk)
add_library(opencv-lib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(opencv-lib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/opencl-sdk/libOpenCL.so)
target_link_libraries( demo opencv-lib )
```

With demo being the library my main file is added to. Running the app produces the following error:

```
ld: error: /Users/terdev/AndroidStudioProjects/demo/app/src/main/cpp/opencl-sdk/libOpenCL.so is incompatible with aarch64linux
```

The supported ABI of the SOC of my device is `arm64-v8a`. Is there a work-around for that problem?

Comment: I could fix it. Problem was, that I used `libOpenCL.so` from `/vendor/lib/` which is a 32 bit shared object and my Snapdragon uses the 64-bit mode. So switching to `/vendor/lib64/libOpenCL.so` solved the issue.